# Enter Decimal Value in an apex:input

Tags: visualforce, html, html5, decimal, apexinputfield

I have a form in a Visualforce Page which inputs some data.

I need to have a decimal input in the form

I am using the following :

```
<th style="word-wrap:break-word; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; text-align: right; ">
                    Marketing Fee<apex:input value="{!marketingFee}" type="number"/>
 </th>
```

Here I am using apex:input instead of apex:inputField because this particular form is not tagged to any object record.

However, the above piece of code is not letting me enter any kind of decimal value and it throwing an error of Invalid Type. I tried with type="decimal" but that does not work either.

Comment: does your VF page have `<apex:page docType="html-5.0" .../>` ?

Comment: @cropredy Yes it does!

Comment: use [edit] and show the controller property for `marketingFee`